# IOCTL call and checking return value

Tags: ioctl, errno

```
if((err = ioctl(fd, IOC_CARD_LOCK, &lock)) < 0)
{
     printf("ioctl failed and returned errno %d \n",err);
}
```

Is the above code correct and a good programming practice? It does compile on my PC.
i.e does it populate `err` with the return value of `ioctl` and check if `err` is `< 0`

Is the above method a standard way to return "err" returned by IOCTL.

There seem to be some standard variable called errno?
what is it? Will that be the same as above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out a better way to do this.

```
if(ioctl(fd, IOC_CARD_LOCK, &lock) < 0)
{
     printf("ioctl failed and returned errno %s \n",strerror(errno));
}
```

errno is a global variable that is set for system calls.and strerror converts the code (a negative integer) into a meaningful string ("Invalid argument" for example.)

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled over this response. The answer is only partly correct, as printf might overwrite errno - according to the man pages it's mandatory to save errno. So a more robust answer is:

```
if(ioctl(fd, IOC_CARD_LOCK, &lock) < 0)
{
    int errsv = errno;
    printf("ioctl failed and returned errno %s \n",strerror(errsv));
}
```

Comment: But isn't C call by value? Won't `strerror(errno)` be evaluated before `printf` is even called?