# Can ioctl system calls in linux be interrupted by signals?

Tags: linux, system-calls

since signals are asynchronous in nature there is a chance that it can interrupt a process whenever a process is running in kernel mode or user Mode.

For example, In Robert Love's system programming , read function was done which checks for -EINTR and will restart the system call with remaining bytes to read.

```
ssize_t ret;
while (len != 0 && (ret = read (fd, buf, len)) != 0) {
  if (ret == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR)
      continue;
    perror ("read");
    break;
  }
  len -= ret;
  buf += ret;
}
```

I came across few ioctl calls from userspace which simply return error by checking the error code < 0. I found similar thing was done in the below link as well.

[IOCTL call and checking return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968238/ioctl-call-and-checking-return-value)

will same mechanism(checking -EINTR in read call) be needed for other system calls like ioctl? Is is always necessary to check the return code for every system call for -EINTR irrespective of whether my program involves signal handling or not?

I also heard about the automatic restart functionality supported by linux for certain system calls, so drivers return -ERESTARTSYS if corresponding ioctl call fails, but i am not sure ioctl system all will come under this category and will be restarted transparently so userspace donot have to worry about ioctl failure due to signal interruption?

What happens if ioctl was partially executed and signal interrupted in the middle? Is still kernel automatically restart the ioctl call without userspace involvement?

Answer (score 1):

Ioctl is a device driver wilcard call (meaning that the driver is free to implement whatever functionality it wants, sleeping or not), so if it decides to sleep on an event, **it decides also if it wants to be interrupted by a kernel interrupt**.  If it decides not to be interrupted, the kernel will handle the interrupt only after the process wakes up (or will deliver it to another thread that is not in such a state)

Anyway, interrupts are delivered to user process *only in user mode*, so never the kernel will suspend a system call, to go user mode to execute the user signal handler, then return to kernel mode to end the system call in course.  This would break the atomicity of system calls.  If the ioctl call sleeps in non-interruptible mode, the signal will have to wait and any handler (or system action in due to the interrupt) will happen **after** the ioctl call.

In multithreaded environments, a process with multiple threads can receive the interrupt (another, different thread) if one of the threads is in such a situation.  The kernel simply delivers the signal to one of the available threads that is able to handle it.